# Property returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```js
  private dataFromBackend: IprofileData;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(result => {
      this.dataFromBackend = result;
    });
    console.log(this.dataFromBackend);
  }
```

`result` returns all the data that I need but `this.dataFromBackend` returns *undefined*. I have also changed `IprofileData` to `any` but it still returns *undefined*. Why?

Comment: arrow functions, let, const, and new javascript have various ways of handliing 'this'
dataFromBackend is not owned by this new function which is assigning result. 
the function assigning result has its own scope.. check out async, await and google "arrow functions and the this keyword"

Comment: A side note: changing the type to `any` wouldn't ever do anything, because type annotations aren't actually enforced on the data - they're only there for the developer's benefit, and don't even exist after the code is transpiled to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log(this.dataFromBackend)` shows up as undefined because it is getting executed before what's inside of the `subscribe` block. The `subscribe` is asynchronous and runs at a later point in time.

If you want to log it out to the console, you have to do what Tamas Szoke did in his first answer.

In the `async/await` way you have to convert the observable into a promise like so:

```
async ngOnInit() {
 this.dataFromBackend = await this.profileService.getEntities().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
 console.log(this.dataFromBackend);
}
```

Keep in mind that converting it to a promise reacts once and completes. If you want to always react to emissions, you have to go the `subscribe` route.

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log` is not waiting for the `profileService` to complete, put your log into the callback:

```
private dataFromBackend: IprofileData;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(result => {
      this.dataFromBackend = result;
      console.log(this.dataFromBackend);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have tried your option with Async/Await but it still returns as undefined.

Comment: I don't think you can do `await this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe()`, it should be `await this.profileService.getEntities().pipe(take(1)).toPromise()`.